# How special is the Solar system compared with other planetary systems?

Tags: solar-system

For example:

Most planets have circular orbit

What else?

Comment: There's no shortage of articles on this if you just google "How weird/unique/strange is our Solar System", but the truth is, we're only beginning to get an idea of what other solar systems are like and small or distant planets are still difficult to detect, so there's much still to be learned.      You might be interested in this:   http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/our-solar-system/56-our-solar-system/planets-and-dwarf-planets/general-questions/221-why-is-our-solar-system-so-different-from-all-the-others-we-ve-found-intermediate